# MKMapView reset back to world view: Rebaked

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

I have been having ongoing memory leak problems with MKMapView (reported to Apple, but no response), and so as a work-around I tried to just allocate one MKMapView and re-use that map instead of reallocating a new one. The problem I'm running into with this is I have yet to be able to reset the MKMapView to the view it starts with. I assume because I'm working from the USA, I initially get a view like this:

[image: map of USA]
<sub>(source: [cprince.com](http://www.cprince.com/stackoverflow/map1.png))</sub>

With this code:

```
static MKMapView *map = nil;

- (void) showUserLocation {    
    [map setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;

    coord.latitude = 39.0; // changed from original coords
    coord.longitude = -105.0;

    MKCoordinateRegion r = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 1000, 1000);

    [map setRegion:r animated:YES];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (! map) {
        CGRect r = CGRectMake(20, 50, 196, 75);
        map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:r];

        defaultRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(map.centerCoordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(180, 360));
    } else {
        [map setRegion:defaultRegion animated:YES];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:map];
}

- (IBAction)annotateMap:(id)sender {
    [self showUserLocation];
}
```

when I click on the button that calls annotateMap, I get the following map (no surprises yet):

[image: map of my home]
<sub>(source: [cprince.com](http://www.cprince.com/stackoverflow/map2.png))</sub>

then, when I navigate away (using a navigation controller) from this view and then re-enter the view (viewWillAppear is again called, but this time it re-uses the MKMapView previously allocated), I get the following map view:

[image: map of ocean]
<sub>(source: [cprince.com](http://www.cprince.com/stackoverflow/map3.png))</sub>

and of course I should be getting the original default region because of this part of the viewWillAppear:

```
        defaultRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(map.centerCoordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(180, 360));
    } else {
        [map setRegion:defaultRegion animated:YES];
    }
```

It doesn't matter if do the setRegion after the addSubview or before. That is, the change below doesn't correct the probelem:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    BOOL firstTime = NO;
    if (! map) {
        firstTime = YES;
        CGRect r = CGRectMake(20, 50, 196, 75);
        map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:r];

        defaultRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(map.centerCoordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(180, 360));
    }

    [self.view addSubview:map];
    if (! firstTime) {
        [map setRegion:defaultRegion animated:YES];
    }
}
```

and using MKMapRectWorld doesn't help either:

```
defaultRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(MKMapRectWorld);
```

The problem is also not due to some kind of race condition with MKMapView. If I alter the handler for the button:

```
- (IBAction)annotateMap:(id)sender {
    defaultRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(map.centerCoordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(180, 360));
    [self showUserLocation];
}
```

and wait until the map is settled on the USA view before I click the button, the problem is the same.

I am using iOS 6.1.2 and XCode 4.6.

(The full XCode project is available at http://www.cprince.com/stackoverflow/Map.zip).

Thoughts?

FIRST CHANGE

I made the defaultRegion a static instead of an instance variable and this doesn't change the situation markedly. (I reported the lat/long for the default region below). Here's the result in the map:

[image: map of ocean]
<sub>(source: [cprince.com](http://www.cprince.com/stackoverflow/map4.png))</sub>

For clarity, the code as it stands now is:

```
static MKMapView *map = nil;
static MKCoordinateRegion defaultRegion;

- (void) showUserLocation {    
    [map setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.latitude = 39.0; // changed from original
    coord.longitude = -105.0;

    MKCoordinateRegion r = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 1000, 1000);

    [map setRegion:r animated:YES];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    BOOL firstTime = NO;
    if (! map) {
        firstTime = YES;
        CGRect r = CGRectMake(20, 50, 196, 75);
        map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:r];

        defaultRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(map.centerCoordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(180, 360));

        NSLog(@"defaultRegion: center: lat: %f, long: %f; span: %f dlat: dlong: %f", defaultRegion.center.latitude, defaultRegion.center.longitude, defaultRegion.span.latitudeDelta, defaultRegion.span.longitudeDelta);
        //defaultRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(MKMapRectWorld);
    }

    [self.view addSubview:map];
    if (! firstTime) {
        NSLog(@"defaultRegion: center: lat: %f, long: %f; span: %f dlat: dlong: %f", defaultRegion.center.latitude, defaultRegion.center.longitude, defaultRegion.span.latitudeDelta, defaultRegion.span.longitudeDelta);
        [map setRegion:defaultRegion animated:YES];
    }
}

- (IBAction)annotateMap:(id)sender {
    //defaultRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(map.centerCoordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(180, 360));
    [self showUserLocation];
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting the region with the animated property set to NO?

Comment: Have you checked the values in the defaultRegion that you make when the page first loads? Perhaps you are not making the region you think you are. For example if it might be failing because you're not at (0,0) but giving it a span of 180x360 so it would go into invalid coordinates.

Comment: Setting the region with animated set to NO doesn't change the situation. Just tried that.

Comment: If (!firstTime), `defaultRegion` is not initialized.

Comment: And I just put some debugging output in and the default region is: defaultRegion: center: lat: 30.000000, long: -40.000000; span: 180.000000 dlat: dlong: 360.000000; So that should be N 30 latitude and W 40 longitude, and yes indeed that puts us in the middle of the Atlantic ocean. So, the issue seems to be that I'm getting my default coordinates set incorrectly for some reason. (This is the situation after fixing the instance variable issue).

Comment: I was not trying to have showUserLocation update the default region. The purpose of showUserLocation in this example is to reflect my actual code, which is to show another map view, but then when I reenter the page, to show the default region (e.g., USA) again.

Comment: Well, following on that default region value, the map.centerCoordinate is not the value I would expect. Here it is: map.centerCoordinate: lat: 30.000000, long: -40.000000. For the middle of the USA I'd expect something like lat: 40, long: -100. Sounds like an Apple bug...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make your view controller a `delegate` for the `MKMapView` and implement `regionDidChangeAnimated`, you'll see that when you first create a map view, the `centerCoordinate` is `30, -40`, but it's subsequently set to `37.178181, -96.054581` (for U.S. users, at least). You apparently can't rely upon the `region` and/or `centerCoordinate` immediately after creating the map view. You have to give it a chance to reset its `region`, which apparently happens asynchronously.

If you want to save the `defaultRegion` after the `MKMapView` sets it the first time, set the `delegate` property of the `MKMapView` and then implement:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    static BOOL firstTime = YES;
    if (firstTime)
    {
        defaultRegion = mapView.region;
        firstTime = NO;
    }
}
```

Note, on `viewWillDisappear`, since you've made your map a `static`, make sure to `nil` the map's `delegate` (since that old view controller will disappear). If you want to continue to have your new instance of the view controller to be a `MKMapViewDelegate`, then just set the `delegate` again when you re-add the map view to your new instance of your detail view controller.

---

Old answer:

When you set `defaultRegion`, that's an instance variable. Thus, that's lost when you dismiss the view. When you come back to the map (i.e. `firstTime` is `NO`), the `defaultRegion` is never initialized, and thus is 0,0, and thus is in the middle of the Atlantic Ocean.

You're obviously not saving the `defaultRegion` (generally you'd have a protocol to pass that back to the master view controller), which makes it hard for the app to know what to do when you select the item in the master view again.

Comment: See my comments above. Yes, this should have worked. But it didn't.

Comment: @ChrisPrince Ok, you're now (by making `defaultRegion` static) saving the `defaultRegion` properly. The next issue is that you're setting `defaultRegion` immediately after the `MKMapView` is created, but the process of setting the region to cover the US happens asynchronously. See my updated answer.

Comment: @ChrisPrince I've added the code for saving the `defaultRegion`.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks! I made that change and one other one. I put the initial map creation into the app delegate because I don't always use the default region the first time I create the map. I've put the updated code here: http://www.cprince.com/stackoverflow/Map2.zip